# GLSL GLTF Instanced Hardware Skinning

Tags: glsl, instancing, skinning

I'm beating my head on trying to get hardware skinning going in my engine.
We're using [OZZ Animation](https://github.com/guillaumeblanc/ozz-animation) and [TinyGLTF](https://github.com/syoyo/tinygltf) together to animate models.

The issue seems to either stem from how OZZ maps their joint id's vs how I grab them out of the .gltf file using TinyGLTF or how the inverse bind poses are mapped when loading the .gltf file.

When loading a model, we map joint names to id's and grab the bind poses:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < model.skins.size(); i++)
{
    tinygltf::Skin _Skin = model.skins[i];
    
    for (auto& JointID : _Skin.joints)
    {
        std::string NodeName = model.nodes[JointID].name;
        Infos->JointMap_[NodeName] = JointID - _Skin.skeleton;
    }

    if (_Skin.inverseBindMatrices > -1)
    {
        const tinygltf::Accessor& acc = model.accessors[_Skin.inverseBindMatrices];
        const tinygltf::BufferView& bufview = model.bufferViews[acc.bufferView];
        const tinygltf::Buffer& buf = model.buffers[bufview.buffer];
        Infos->InverseBindMatrices.resize(acc.count);
        memcpy(Infos->InverseBindMatrices.data(), &buf.data[acc.byteOffset + bufview.byteOffset], acc.count * sizeof(glm::mat4));

        break;
    }
}
```

`Infos` is just a struct that holds our loaded model data.

`Infos->JointMap_` is `std::map<std::string, uint16_t> JointMap_ = {};`

`Infos->InverseBindMatrices` is `std::vector<glm::mat4> InverseBindMatrices = {};`

We pass our Infos structure off and later when rendering the object, we use the data to animate our model:

```
auto joints = skeleton_.num_joints();
for (int i = 0; i < joints; i++)
{
    const char* OZZ_JointName = skeleton_.joint_names()[i];
    uint16_t GLFW_JointIndex = _GLTFJointMap[OZZ_JointName];

    glm::mat4 OZZ_Matrix = to_mat4(models_[i]);
    glm::mat4 GLFW_Matrix = InverseBindMatrices_[GLFW_JointIndex];

    if (_Mesh->bAnimated && i < 32)
    {
        _Mesh->instanceData_Animation[instanceIndex].bones[GLFW_JointIndex] = OZZ_Matrix * GLFW_Matrix;
    }
}
```

Iterate through all the joints in our skeleton.

For each joint get the joint name.

From this name get the gltf joint index.

Take the ozz model space animation matrix and multiply it with the gltf inverse bind pose, and update each bone on our model to hold the computed matrix.

The data is uploaded to our vertex shader and used to display the animated model:

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec4 inPosition;
//layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 inTexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 inNormal;
layout(location = 4) in vec3 inTangent;
layout(location = 5) in vec4 inBones;
layout(location = 6) in vec4 inWeights;

layout(std140, binding = 0) readonly buffer InstanceData {
    mat4 model[];
} ssbo;

layout (binding = 1) uniform UBO {
    mat4 view_proj;
} ubo;

layout(std140, binding = 2) readonly buffer InstanceData_Animated {
    mat4 Matrices[32];
} Joint[];

layout(location = 0) out vec3 outNormal;
layout(location = 1) out vec2 outUV;
//layout(location = 2) out vec3 outColor;
layout(location = 3) out vec4 outWorldPos;
layout(location = 4) out vec3 outTangent;

void main() {
    outWorldPos = ssbo.model[gl_InstanceIndex] * inPosition;
    outUV = inTexCoord;
    //outColor = inColor;

    mat4 skinMat =
        inWeights.x * Joint[0].Matrices[int(inBones.x)] +
        inWeights.y * Joint[0].Matrices[int(inBones.y)] +
        inWeights.z * Joint[0].Matrices[int(inBones.z)] +
        inWeights.w * Joint[0].Matrices[int(inBones.w)];

    //gl_Position = ubo.view_proj * ssbo.model[gl_InstanceIndex] * inPosition;
    gl_Position = ubo.view_proj * ssbo.model[gl_InstanceIndex] * skinMat * inPosition;
    
    
    mat3 mNormal = transpose(inverse(mat3(ssbo.model[gl_InstanceIndex])));
    outNormal = mNormal * normalize(inNormal);
    outTangent = mNormal * normalize(inTangent);

}
```

Which ends up giving us something like this:

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

(not my screenshots, used to illustrate the issue).

My shader code should be fine. If I painstakingly manually map the joint names to joint index by hand, I can get correct output. This manual mapping was fine to help figure out where the issue was in my program, but needs to be programmatically computed when loading the model for obvious reasons.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here??